# Why does my code accept the input but still prints out the error?

Tags: c#, console-application

Some background: This is a login system, it checks the input inside a text file. I use list<> for this and a foreach loop. And if it matches the saved lines, then it will be valid. So, if it's not then print out: a not valid message.

There's two lines in this text document and the program reads all the lines as it should, and it's valid etc. The first line does not print out a "not valid message" but the second line does and still is acceptable.

```
string containDetails = firstName + " " + lastName + " " + password;
        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines (@"D:\LoginSystemFolder\UserDetailFolder\Users.txt").ToList ();
        foreach (var l in lines) {
            if (l.Equals (containDetails)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Login was a success!");
                ls.MainMenu ();
            }
            else if(!l.Equals(containDetails) {
                Console.WriteLine ("The login details are not valid. Are you sure they're correct?");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: Can you share the output exactly? How many lines shown in the console?

Comment: A) what is `ls`?  B) this code is not marking anything as either acceptable or unacceptable, so it’s very unclear what is/should be going on here.  I’d suggest showing us the rest of the relevant code in this routine.

Comment: Should you stop the loop after first match is found?

Comment: can you show examples for ``containDetails`` and some lines from ``Users.text``, may be you need to ignore case. **Note** : use just ``else`` instead of ``else if``

Comment: If your lines are different then you will get the "not valid message" always because you are comparing containDetails against each line in the document... one could match but the rest wouldn't...

Comment: consider: what happens when `ls.MainMenu()` returns?

Comment: "ls" stands for LoginSystem and it's for the main menu after the login window. The rest of the program is just save input and write it all to a text file. And the text file only contains: line 1: Mark Morgan 123
line 2: John Snow 456 a

Comment: To clarify: I have class 1(Right now it's called LoginSystem and yes I will rename it): This one is for saving user logins to a text file and its the class for the main menu. Class 2: is for the login window(this one I'm currently having problems with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exit your loop when it is found and also would be best to just move your next step outside. Also, your code was missing a parenthesis on the last `If` statement. Notice how I use actual strings in my example so it is more clear what is expected... this helps people understand the problem better. Debugging your code would easily show you where your logic is not working.

```
string containDetails = "Mark Morgan 123";
List<string> lines = new List<string>() {"Mark Morgan 123", "John Snow 456"};
bool successfulLogIn = false;
foreach (var l in lines) {
    if (l.Equals (containDetails)) {
        successfulLogIn = true;
        break; //exit loop
       // ls.MainMenu (); MOVING THIS OUTSIDE OF LOOP
    }
}

if(successfulLogIn){    
     Console.WriteLine("Login was a success!");
     // ls.MainMenu (); //call this here
}else{
    Console.WriteLine ("The login details are not valid. Are you sure they're correct?");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I should've thought about this more. ugh, feel so stupid.